# Using last active text input box to run search

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have three text input boxes that run the same PHP script. The PHP script checks to see if each is empty and generates a search results page. The problem is, the script gets the first input box that is full. For example, if I fill out A then B and then run the search while B is active and was the latest filled, it returns results for A. Same problem if I fill out A then C and B then C.

I've been trying to find a way to get the correct search without having to resort to splitting up the script and attaching each separate script to a separate input box, because making changes later would be a pain.

Comment: Why don't you give all three boxes different names, and then check the last one first?

Comment: Because it would be the same problem, but in opposite order.

Comment: Why do you have 3 search boxes? Post your code.

Comment: You can't detect which box was touched last using PHP.  You'll want to use the `onBlur` or `onFocus` event in Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach an `onfocus` event to each box that records which box is active. Then, attach an `onsubmit` to the form that checks which box was last active. Blank the other two, then submit the form. Something like this (untested):

**HTML:**

```
<form action="phpscript.php" onsubmit="checkLastActive();">
Input 1: <input type="text" name="box1" id="box1" onfocus="lastActive=this.id"><br>
Input 2: <input type="text" name="box2" id="box2" onfocus="lastActive=this.id"><br>
Input 3: <input type="text" name="box3" id="box3" onfocus="lastActive=this.id"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var lastActive="";
function checkLastActive() {
    for (var i=1; i<4; i++) {
        if (lastActive != "box" + i) document.getElementById("box" + i).value="";
    }
}
```